# Ionic value from variable not shown in html

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I created a new Ionic app and tried to display a value from a variable in HTML but i can't get it working.

This is my page, I didn't change anything. I just created the app.

```js
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';
import { SongsProviderService } from '../Services/songs-provider.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }])
    ],
    declarations: [Tab1Page]
})

export class Tab1PageModule {

    songs: any;
    bla: any;

    constructor(public songsService: SongsProviderService) {
        this.bla = "sss";
        console.log(this.bla);
    }

}
```

HTML:

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
            Tab One
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-content>
        <p>Test {{bla}}</p>
    </ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting. Does the page display but `{{bla}}` just outputs an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the reason is due to the fact that are two `<ion-content>` elements. This article states that there should just be one: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content